# Making hls files with -hls_time > 10

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am building a local app for watching local videos from the browser, because of some of the videos beeing over 1hour they started to lagg out and using HLS instead of .mp4 solved this.

In the app I'm building the user will often skip 10-40 seconds forward.
My question is: Should I use `-hls_time 60` or would it be better to just use `-hls_time 10`

Current code: `ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod -f hls "input\index.m3u8"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longer segments imply greater segment sizes so after a seek the player might take longer to resume depending on the available bandwidth and whether the required segment has already been retrieved or not.

If the app is intended for mobile devices where network conditions are expected to vary you will also need to consider adaptive streaming. In this case, with longer segments you will see less quality switching but you risk stalling the playback. You can find a more detailed article [here](https://bitmovin.com/mpeg-dash-hls-segment-length/).

Some observations about your `ffmpeg` command:

- don't set the `level` as it's already auto-calculated if not specified and you risk getting it wrong and messing device compatibility checks.
- segments are cut only on keyframes and their duration can be greater than the specified `hls_time`. If you need precise segment durations you need to insert a keyframe at the desired interval.

Comment: Does it really matter, see the first sentence: *I am building a local app for watching local videos from the browser,*

Comment: @Gyan it's *local* in the beginning, then someone thinks it's a good idea, then it goes into production and then I have to deal with it on the player's side